# control monitor for application via C++

Tags: c++, winapi, monitor

I have an application that opens up IE browser windows at certain intervals throughout the day. I would like to control the monitor that the browser window opens up to (for example browser1 opens on monitor1 and browser2 on monitor2 and browser3 on monitor1 and browser4 on monitor2). Is there a way using C++ (app is written in C++) to control the monitor that I open the browser window on?

Answer (score 1):

There are various third-party utilities that will allow a user to control this, but programatically you would have to use something like GetMonitorInfo / MoveWindow to position IE after launching it.

An alternative would be to embed an IE control in a dialog or window of your choosing which you would then have complete control over.